# How to set scrollview in a dialog activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I want my dialog activity to scroll the view inside it. I am using several edit text in it. adding more items in layout increase the size of dialog activity. which I do not want . Below is my xml file of dialog activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_offer_coffee"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/et_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:hint="Enter Email"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter contact_number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/et_contact" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter Address"
        android:id="@+id/et_address" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_coffee_brand"
        android:hint="Enter Coffee Brand"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_num_person1"
        android:hint="Enter Num Of Person"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_num_person2"
        android:hint="Enter Num Of Person"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_num_person3"
        android:hint="Enter Num Of Person"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

please tell me how to do this , I tried many links but nothing really worked for me.Please help

Comment: But your layout looks OK.

Comment: yeah I have done this before that works for me , but now its not